# String update using int variable

Tags: java

I have a string 2.0.0.3 and a int value 4

What will be the simplest way to update the string like 2.0.0.4.

Tried using `StringBuilder` and `chatAt`

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(name);
myName.setCharAt(3,(char) value);
```

However sysout of myname gives a square instead of 2004.

Comment: Post what have you tried. We don't tend to give straight code for this kind of questions.

Comment: What is the logic of replacement of 3 with 4?

Comment: It's not the third character you should be replacing, it's the last (or before last).

Comment: you don't want to setCharAt to value because value is an int, you need the character '4' (ascii 52) not the integer 4 (which is the ascii character EOT (end of transmission)).  Also setCharAt takes an index, not the value of the character you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(name); myName.setCharAt(6,(char) ('0'+value));
```

(BTW this is rather bad style, I am sure others will come up with cleaner solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
char replacementChar = (char) ('0' + value);
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(name);
myName.setCharAt(6,replacementChar);
```

May I suggest however to use a different technique to update that String?

It should be wiser to use a class to model it and build it entirely by implementing a toString().

```
public class Version {
    private final static String SEPARATOR = ".";//Note separator could be a field instead of a contant
    private int major;
    private int minor;
    private int incremental;
    private int buildVersion;

    public Version(int major, int minor, int incremental, int buildVersion) {
        this.major = major;
        this.minor = minor;
        this.incremental = incremental;
        this.buildVersion = buildVersion;
    }
    /**
     * Populates this class from String
     * @param version a version number made of numbers separated by a dot
     */
    public Version(String version) {
        if(version != null){
            String[] numbers = version.split("\\" + SEPARATOR);
            if(numbers.length>0) major = toInt(numbers[0]);
            if(numbers.length>1) minor = toInt(numbers[1]);
            if(numbers.length>2) incremental = toInt(numbers[2]);
            if(numbers.length>3) buildVersion = toInt(numbers[3]);
        }
    }
    private int toInt(String strVal){
        int val = 0;
        try {
            val = Integer.parseInt(strVal);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // TODO replace this, please
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }
    /**
     * @return the major
     */
    public int getMajor() {
        return major;
    }
    /**
     * @param major the major to set
     */
    public void setMajor(int major) {
        this.major = major;
    }
    /**
     * @return the minor
     */
    public int getMinor() {
        return minor;
    }
    /**
     * @param minor the minor to set
     */
    public void setMinor(int minor) {
        this.minor = minor;
    }
    /**
     * @return the incremental
     */
    public int getIncremental() {
        return incremental;
    }
    /**
     * @param incremental the incremental to set
     */
    public void setIncremental(int incremental) {
        this.incremental = incremental;
    }
    /**
     * @return the buildVersion
     */
    public int getBuildVersion() {
        return buildVersion;
    }
    /**
     * @param buildVersion the buildVersion to set
     */
    public void setBuildVersion(int buildVersion) {
        this.buildVersion = buildVersion;
    }
    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return major + SEPARATOR + minor + SEPARATOR + incremental + SEPARATOR + buildVersion;
    }
}
```

This class could be used this way :

```
Version version = new Version("2.0.0.3");//could be new Version(2, 0, 0, 3)
version.setBuildVersion(4);
System.out.println(version);
```